# Is there anyone who can help me get this setinterval fuction working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I am pretty new to this whole jquery and javascript thing as I have really worked with server side languages. However, I have a challenge here where If the specific data received($status) is not the same with the one provided(queu or successf), the page should reload to fetch the data($status), and it should do this to a set number of time, if it reloads the page according to the number of time set; whether or not the data($status) is returned true, I want it to entirely stop reloading the page and exit.I have tried doing it this way; but I am not quite sure what I am missing.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var number_of_time_loaded = 7000;
  var queue = '$status';
  var inter;

  if (queue == 'queu' || queue == 'successf') {
    alert('successfully uploaded');
  } else {
    alert('kindly wait for some minutes');

    for (;number_of_time_loaded < 70000;) {
      inter = setInterval(function() {
        window.location.reload(1);
      }, number_of_time_loaded++);

      if (number_of_time_loaded >= 21000) {
        clearInterval(inter);
      } else {
        number_of_time_loaded++
      }
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `for (number_of_time_loaded < 70000)` is invalid syntax

Comment: Hi!, after every page reload you code is start from beggining, you can use local storage or session storage for save you reload interrations

Comment: And like @adiga say for is invalid syntax [for MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: Added a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992). Please add the missing brackets and fix the syntax errors.

Comment: Hey @Greg-- if you have some time please could you demonstrate this in code...:)

Comment: @adiga okay I will sure check that out:)

Comment: What should be the *specific data received*? What value is changing when you reload the page?

Comment: `for (number_of_time_loaded < 70000)` looks like it should be `while (number_of_time_loaded < 70000)` - *but* I'm not sure this is the correct approach - you should consider only (re)loading parts of the page that change, using ajax.  `window.location.reload` will stop the execution of your javascript intervals on the page and start a whole new page - so there's never any point calling it more than once

Comment: 1. change for statement to if
2. please give more information - in your example first statement <7000 is false because its === 7000 not less so timer didn't start count
3. task not clear what do you want to create

Comment: )) yes , i don't see one `0` in the end. But logic is: first intereation if < 70000 => true   start interval => after 7000 ms reload page and start script from beggining

Comment: And what mean `1` inside `window.location.reload(1)` i didn/t see documentation about it [location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

Comment: `for (number_of_time_loaded < 70000) {` is still not clear, what do you want? its while or if statement ?

Comment: @adiga wow the snipet worked wonders and I believe from there I can forge it to become exactly how I wanted it. :)

Comment: @Greg-- reload used to have a non-standard force flag

Comment: If you reload the page, the JavaScript after it is not going to run.... so really unclear what you are expecting to happen here. That means the "tracking" number or reloads will be reset every time the page loads.

Comment: @Greg-- I say it here..<https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp> I omitted the semicolons also.

Comment: Your code is really unclear.... you have a hard coded variable `var queue = '$status';` Are you expecting this to change?How is it changing since it is not changing in the code provided.

Comment: Excluding the _other_ issues, only the last created interval is stored in `inter`, the previous values being overwritten. So only the last interval can be cleared.

Comment: yes @epascarello ..that is a variable inside php file... it is changing.

Comment: So it looks like `"<?php echo $status; ?>";` in the real code?

Comment: @epascarello I am actually echoing every of the code in php file..I don't have a problem with the php aspect...I just had challenge with the javascript part.

Comment: No, I am trying to get an understanding of what exactly you are doing....

Comment: @epascarello I undated the question

Answer (score 0):

So you checking a variable that is written by PHP. You are saying if this variable is not a certain value, you want the page to reload after a set period of time. Refreshing the page will reset the JavaScript variables so you would have to use local storage to keep the state.

```
var maxAttempts = 10;
var queue = "<?php echo $status; ?>";
if (queue == 'queu' || queue == 'successf') { 
  // it is updated
  console.log("Updated);
  sessionStorage.removeItem("attempts");
} else {
  var currentAttempts = sessionStorage.getItem("attempts") || 0;
  currentAttempts++;
  if (currentAttempts < maxAttempts) {
    console.log("waiting for another attempt");
    sessionStorage.setItem("attempts", currentAttempts);
    window.setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(); }, 5000); // wait 5 seconds
  } else {
    // too many attempts made
    console.log("too many attempts made");
    sessionStorage.removeItem("attempts");
  }
}
```

Better solution would be an Ajax request instead of refreshing the page. An
other option is setting meta refresh header in PHP and not having to use JavaScript.

So in the PHP if variable is not set, you echo out `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">`

Comment: where is the "attempts" defined in sessionStorage.removeItem("attempts") please?

Comment: What do you mean where it is defined. session storage is local storage in the browser. It is being set in the code.